# [AVPlayerLayer superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, avfoundation, avplayerlayer

In my storyboard I put a view inside of my UIViewController.
I added necessary parameters there:

[image]

and connected it with my code:

[image]

In the code I have:

```
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

@IBOutlet weak var yawpVideo: AVPlayerLayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: videoURL)!

    player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    yawpVideo.player = player
    player.play()
}
```

and that causes error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVPlayerLayer superview]:
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe320cb2030'
```

Can you tell me what causes this problem and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UIView` is not a `CALayer`, you cannot add an `AVPlayerLayer` to the storyboard.

Instead, after your view has loaded, programmatically add your AVPlayer's `playerLayer` to the UIView's layer.

Change your outlet to be a `UIView`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yawpVideo: UIView!
```

Then, add the layer:

```
player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
yawpVideo.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks man, it worked, I also had to put some constraints programatically: `playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)`, now the video is in the center of the screen - how can I make it so that it starts from the very top of the screen?

Comment: @user3766930 those are not constraints, you are manually setting the frame of the layer.  If you want to change the player layer to be in the center of the screen, add constraints to your `yawpVideo` view in the Storyboard.